Getting ECONNREFUSED while trying to expose local Twilio function via ngrok
I'm trying to expose my locally running Twilio function via ngrok.
According to the documentation npx twilio-run --ngrok should do the trick; however, I'm getting the following error:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4041
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 4041
}

I tried:

uninstalling and installing ngrok again and using different account
exposing another app via standard ngrok like ngrok http 8000 and it works, but if I do it with the above Twilio command I'll always get the same error message

I'm thinking if it could be some sort of permission issue, but not sure. What could be the issue here?

Can you open an issue in the github repo?
